# Display Result in editBox Android Studio and button Listeners

Tags: java, android

There are currently no errors besides my logical one I assume.  The emulator launches but when buttons are clicked the homework app crashes do I need to add onClickListeners to each one of the buttons or is there something else that is an issue.  Thanks for the help

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Button one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        one.setOnClickListener(this); // calling onClick() method
        Button two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        two.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        three.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button four = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        four.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        EditText myTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);

        String n1 = myTxt.getText().toString();

        int x = Integer.parseInt(n1);

        EditText myTxt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);

        String n2 = myTxt2.getText().toString();

        int y = Integer.parseInt(n2);

        EditText result = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText6);

        int z = 0;



        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.button1:
                z = x + y;
                break;

            case R.id.button2:
                z = x - y;
                break;

            case R.id.button3:
                z = x * y;
                break;

            case R.id.button4:
                if (y != 0) {

                    z = x / y;

                    break;
                }


                else {

                    EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
                    text.setText("Cannot Divide By Zero");
                    break;

                }

            default:
                break;

        }

        result.setText(z);
    }

    }
```

06-01 13:10:58.285 10844-10844/com.example.andrey.homework E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-01 13:10:58.285 10844-10844/com.example.andrey.homework E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.andrey.homework, PID: 10844
06-01 13:10:58.285 10844-10844/com.example.andrey.homework E/AndroidRuntime: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
06-01 13:10:58.285 10844-10844/com.example.andrey.homework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:312)
06-01 13:10:58.285 10844-10844/com.example.andrey.homework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getText(ResourcesWrapper.java:52)
06-01 13:10:58.285 10844-10844/com.example.andrey.homework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4417)
06-01 13:10:58.285 10844-10844/com.example.andrey.homework E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.andrey.homework.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:112)
06-01 13:10:58.285 10844-10844/com.example.andrey.homework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
06-01 13:10:58.285 10844-10844/com.example.andrey.homework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
06-01 13:10:58.285 10844-10844/com.example.andrey.homework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
06-01 13:10:58.285 10844-10844/com.example.andrey.homework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-01 13:10:58.285 10844-10844/com.example.andrey.homework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
06-01 13:10:58.285 10844-10844/com.example.andrey.homework E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
06-01 13:10:58.285 10844-10844/com.example.andrey.homework E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-01 13:10:58.285 10844-10844/com.example.andrey.homework E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
06-01 13:10:58.285 10844-10844/com.example.andrey.homework E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: Why do you get `R.id.editText4` twice in your code? And, in your console, there should be an exception comming out, if your emulator is crashing.

Comment: please post your error log to better help.

Comment: I hope that your editbox contents are not well formatted to be able to be converted to integer. if you post your error log i can help you better.

Comment: You should use `result.setText(String.valueOf(z));`

Comment: That solved the issue, Thanks Titus!  The only other problem is how to get rid off error message after changing number values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the stack trace, the problem seems to be this call `result.setText(z)`.

The `setText(int resid)` method that you've used, sets the `EditText` view's text to a `String` resource with the id you've passed as a parameter to this function and the problem is that there isn't any resource with that id.

What you should use instead is `result.setText(String.valueOf(z))`, use the `setText(String str)` method. This will set the `EditText` view's text to the value of the `z` variable.

In response to your comment: "how to get rid off error message after changing number values ?"

You can do something like this:

```
EditText myTxt = ...;
EditText myTxt2 = ...;
EditText result = ...;

TextWatcher w = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        if("Cannot Divide By Zero".equals(result.getText().toString())){// the "result" contains the error message
            if(editable.matches("^\\-?\\d+$")){// the `EditText` contain a number (can be a negative number).
                result.setText("");// clear the error message.
            }
        }
    }
};

myTxt.addTextChangedListener(w);
myTxt2.addTextChangedListener(w);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   EditText myTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
   EditText myTxt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
```

Check this 2 line... May be you refer same id.

Please share the log.